# Mixing WebForms and MVC5 routing not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, webforms-routing

I have below code for my routing for web forms and MVC.

MVC routing seems to be working fine but not the web form when I mix both.

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("");

    //MVC        
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    //WebForms
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "myPage",
        "page/companyInfo/{*queryvalues}",
        "~/company/details.aspx"
        );
```

Do I need to write a IgnoreRoute statement for details.aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the routes, the MVC route should be at the bottom as default is basically a catch-all. MVC process routes from top to bottom, if it finds a match, it stops looking and routes you to the matched route.

```
        //WebForms
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "myPage",
            "page/companyInfo/{*queryvalues}",
            "~/company/details.aspx"
            );

       //MVC        
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I tried moving web forms routing first but still it is refusing to load details.aspx page